# How to map sql reader to list within object

Tags: c#

I have the following data coming from my db:

[image]

and I have the following dtos to fill with this info:

```
public class LanguageDto : ILanguageDto
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }
    public string LangValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CountryFlag> LanguageFlagUrls { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefaultLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class CountryFlag : ICountryFlag
{
    public string FlagUrl { get; set; }
}
```

What would be the best way to place the associated list of flagUrls with only one instance of languageId, LanguageName and LangValue.

So far if I do it like this I get 6 instances in the list:

```
var urls = new List<CountryFlag>();
var unparsedLanguages = new List<LanguageDto>();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    var langDtop = new LanguageDto();
    langDtop.LanguageId = rdr.GetInt32(0);
    langDtop.LanguageName = rdr[1].ToString();
    langDtop.LangValue = rdr[2].ToString();
    langDtop.LanguageFlagUrls = new List<CountryFlag>{new CountryFlag { FlagUrl = rdr[3].ToString()}};
    unparsedLanguages.Add(langDtop);
}
```

or I can do this and only have 3 right instances per lang Value but I dont know how to then make and insert the list of flagUrls to each correspondent LanguageId object:

```
// If we don't have on our list the language id passed in, then let's add it in
if (!availableLanguages.Any(p => p.LanguageId == rdr.GetInt32(0)))
{
    availableLanguages.Add(langDtop);
}
```

Any suggestions maybe without a nested foreach and maybe with just a nice linq expression? Anything will help, thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Direct calling from db to list this is the much better approach

```
//Where TransactionDto is your List 

//And TRANSACTION_ID and FMS_STATUS are Parameters passing

CallStoredProcedureForMultipleTable<TransactionDto, dynamic>(
                                                        "proc_UpdateFmsStatusByTransactionId",
new Dictionary<dynamic, Tuple<dynamic, bool, string>>(){
{ "TRANSACTION_ID" ,Tuple.Create<dynamic,bool,string(l_TransactionDto.Tm_TRANSACTION_ID,false,null)},
{ "FMS_STATUS" ,Tuple.Create<dynamic,bool,string>(FmsStatus.Processed,false,null)}
},
out l_SpResponseCode,
out l_SpResponseDescription);
```

```
 public static List<dynamic> CallStoredProcedureForMultipleTable<T1, T2>(string p_SpName, IDictionary<dynamic, Tuple<dynamic, bool, string>> p_Param, out string p_OutResposneCode, out string p_OutResposneDescription)
    {

        p_OutResposneCode = ResponseCode.Success;
        p_OutResposneDescription = TransactionStatus.Success;
        List<dynamic> retVal = new List<dynamic>();
        List<T1> Type1 = null; List<T2> Type2 = null;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CommonObjects.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(p_SpName, connection))
                {

                    if (connection != null && connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                        connection.Open();
                    }
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    foreach (var data in p_Param)
                    {
                        var sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@" + data.Key, data.Value.Item1);
                        if (data.Value.Item2)
                        {
                            sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                            sqlParam.TypeName = "dbo." + data.Value.Item3;
                        }
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
                    }

                    SqlParameter l_OutResponseCode = new SqlParameter("@ResponseCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(l_OutResponseCode);
                    SqlParameter l_OutResponseDescription = new SqlParameter("@ResponseDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(l_OutResponseDescription);


                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            Type1 = DataReaderMapToList<T1>(reader).ToList();
                            while (reader.NextResult())
                                Type2 = DataReaderMapToList<T2>(reader).ToList();
                        }
                    }
                    p_OutResposneCode = l_OutResponseCode.Value.ToString();
                    p_OutResposneDescription = l_OutResponseDescription.Value.ToString();

                    if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                        connection.Dispose();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    connection.Dispose();
                }

                p_OutResposneCode = ResponseCode.Error;
                p_OutResposneDescription = ex.Message;
                Logger.LogError("OtherServicesBLL", "CallStoredProcedureForMultipleTable ", "Error Stacktrace", ex.StackTrace, "Error Message", ex.Message,"spname", p_SpName);
            }
        }
        retVal.Add(Type1);
        retVal.Add(Type2);
        return retVal;
    }
    public static bool HasColumn(this IDataRecord p_IDataRecord, string p_ColumnName)
    {
        string l_FuncName = "HasColumn";

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p_IDataRecord.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (p_IDataRecord.GetName(i).Equals(p_ColumnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(l_ClassName, l_FuncName, "Error Message", ex.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static List<T> DataReaderMapToList<T>(IDataReader p_DataReader)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        T obj;
        try
        {
            while (p_DataReader.Read())
            {
                obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (p_DataReader.HasColumn(prop.Name) && !object.Equals(p_DataReader[prop.Name], DBNull.Value))
                        prop.SetValue(obj, p_DataReader[prop.Name], null);
                }
                list.Add(obj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError("OtherServicesBll", "DataReaderMapToList ", "Error Stacktrace", ex.StackTrace, "Error Message", ex.Message);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this another answer which is more siutable to you

```
  if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            Type1 = DataReaderMapToList<T1>(reader).ToList();
                            while (reader.NextResult())
                                Type2 = DataReaderMapToList<T2>(reader).ToList();
                        }


//here is the other functions

public static bool HasColumn(this IDataRecord p_IDataRecord, string p_ColumnName)
    {
        string l_FuncName = "HasColumn";

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p_IDataRecord.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (p_IDataRecord.GetName(i).Equals(p_ColumnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(l_ClassName, l_FuncName, "Error Message", ex.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static List<T> DataReaderMapToList<T>(IDataReader p_DataReader)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        T obj;
        try
        {
            while (p_DataReader.Read())
            {
                obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (p_DataReader.HasColumn(prop.Name) && !object.Equals(p_DataReader[prop.Name], DBNull.Value))
                        prop.SetValue(obj, p_DataReader[prop.Name], null);
                }
                list.Add(obj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError("OtherServicesBll", "DataReaderMapToList ", "Error Stacktrace", ex.StackTrace, "Error Message", ex.Message);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: So I adapted the code you gave me but .NextResult never goes to true sadly it wont quite map the list of urls into each object:

                        if (rdr.HasRows)
                        {
                            availableLanguages = DataReaderMapToList<LanguageDto>(rdr).ToList();
                            while (rdr.NextResult())
                                urls = DataReaderMapToList<CountryFlag>(rdr).ToList();
                        }